# Displaying JList

Tags: java, swing

again I am having problems with JList in displaying data from mysql database, I used the code given below but it is not displaying anything on screen..

```
JFrame f8 = new JFrame("Schedule");
f8.setVisible(true);
f8.setSize(1000, 1000);
JPanel jpa1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

String query = "SELECT * FROM Location";
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();
try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/SPL", "root", "PWD");
    stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        String stadium = rs.getString("Stadium");
        String city = rs.getString("City");
        model.addElement(stadium);
        model1.addElement(city);
    }
    JList list = new JList(model);
    JList list1 = new JList(model1);
    f8.add(jpa1);
    jpa1.add(list);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(1);
    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Message   : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

can you tell me please where am I WRONG?

Comment: I would do the following: 1) create your GUI (including your model and your list) *first*, 2) Open the database and read the items into your model (your JList will already have been associated with the model), and 3) use "model.add()".  Here's an example: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/list_listaddrem.html

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  HArd code the data.

Answer (score 7):

It's difficult to say what the problem is based on the snippet of code, not to mention a bit of unformatted code that is difficult to read, but...

- You add one list to a JPanel but then add the same list to a JScrollPane and ignore the JScrollPane.
- You're using GridBagLayout without any GridBagConstraints
- You're doing a lot of JDBC code on the Swing event thread which threatens to lock this thread up.
- You create one JList, list1, but don't add it to anything.

You should consider:

- Testing your database code outside of a GUI. Divide the problem to conquer it else you will have too many variables that can effect your results making it difficult to know what's causing what.
- placing debug statements in your code or use a debugger to first find out where the errors are.
- Posting only well formatted code when asking for volunteers to help. It's hard enough to understand someone else's code that you should strive not to make it any more difficult. We greatly appreciate the effort!

Comment: The *not shows anything* problem is clearly caused by the scroll pane. A Swing component can only have one parent, so adding the list first to the panel and then to the scroll pane removes it from the panel, hence nothing visible. So correctly addressed in this answer, together with all my other remarks. Will hit the +1 button a few times (it is the gesture that counts)

Comment: I disagree. Check the source code for `Container#add`. It checks whether the component has already a parent, and if so, it is removed from the parent. So adding a component to a second container is sufficient to remove it from the previous added `Container`

Comment: @Robin: you're correct. I've deleted my erroneous comment, and thank you

Comment: We are all here to learn. I had to check the source code myself since you made me doubt. Now we are both certain :-)

Answer (score 5):

Hovercraft Full of Eels almost hit the nail on the head, but I forgive him cause until I started taking whole sections of you code out I didn't see it.

The last line of your code reads

```
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
```

You never add this scroll pane to your UI.  It has the effect of removing the `list` from it's previous parent (`jpa1`) and adding to the scroll pane, which leaves nothing to be displayed on the screen.

I'd follow ALL of Hovercraft Full of Eels recommendations and then figure out how to fix this last problem...

```
jpa1.add(new JScrollPane(list));
```

Should just about do it

Comment: It still not working, any SQLException is comming which says- "Message   : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: @RohanSinghDhaka which tells you that there is another problem (unrelated to JList) - you first need to find out how to connect to the db and retrieve data (no gui required, simple use println). If that is working, the JList should be displaying the data just fine (if you follow the answers here :-)

Comment: i used print command to display data, but it still show the same message, i think JList is not creating any problem. But still not getting where i am wrong, i don't think it is because i am running programme on Ubuntu, is it so?

Comment: @RohanSinghDhaka that's expected as long as you don't find out how-to fix the db problem :-) The idea of doing the print is to separate one issue from another, then solve them independently. After that, there's a high probabilty that they work also in combination. So again: _you first need to find out how to connect to the db and retrieve data_